# Move array element with a particular value to top of array

Tags: php

I have an array that looks similar to this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
      [Leasing] => 12939.74
      [Name] => Jeremy
      [Rental] => 0
      [Sales] => 56603.13
      [Total] => 69542.87
    )
  [1] => stdClass Object
    (
      [Leasing] => 0
      [Name] => Shaun
      [Rental] => 0
      [Sales] => 58590
      [Total] => 58590
    )
  [2] => stdClass Object
    (
      [Leasing] => 0
      [Name] => Lindsay
      [Rental] => 0
      [Sales] => 22951.97
      [Total] => 22951.97
    )
  [3] => stdClass Object
    (
      [Leasing] => 0
      [Name] => Sally
      [Rental] => 1200
      [Sales] => 21624.9
      [Total] => 22824.9
    )
  [4] => stdClass Object
    (
      [Leasing] => 0
      [Name] => House
      [Rental] => 0
      [Sales] => 16235.81
      [Total] => 16235.81
    )
  [5] => stdClass Object
    (
      [Leasing] => 5298.85
      [Name] => Bill
      [Rental] => 1200
      [Sales] => 0
      [Total] => 6498.85
    )
)
```

Currently, the array is sorted by total using this:

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return $b->Total - $a->Total;
});
```

Now, I need to be able to ALWAYS have the person with `[Name] => House` to the top of the array. My thoughts are that I can leave it sorted by `Total` (because I still need it that way) and then take the element with the House value and put it at the start of the array. I can take a particular KEY and put it at the top, but the KEY's may change depending on who has the highest total. How can I always put the person named `House` at the top of the array?

Comment: One approach: Put the desired 1st element in the 1st position, split the array into that one element and everything else, and then sort the everything else part.  Sorry, I don't remember PHP syntax well enough to provide a proper answer.

Comment: The return values from your sorting function will be cast as integers by usort, so it will see 0.05 and 0.95 as equal.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work:

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a->Name != "House" && $b->Name == "House") {
        return 1;
    } elseif ($a->Name == "House" && $b->Name != "House") {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return $b->Total - $a->Total;
    }
});
```

From [PHP: usort - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

In this case, return `1` tells the sorting function that `House` is greater than any other value, and `-1` that `House` is lesser than any other value.

Comment: Works brilliantly! If I may ask, what significance does the -1 and 1 have?

Comment: Awesome , would like to know how to make the comparator function parameterized ,as if instead of hardcoding "house" ,how to inject a variable?

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements:

1. Sort by the `Name` column -- position `House` valued rows before non-`House` valued rows.
2. Sort by the `Total` column DESC.

From PHP7, the spaceship operator (`<=>`) makes the scripting the sorting rules very clean by evaluating arrays of rules (reading the elements from left to right).

To sort `House` rows first, evaluate each object's `Name` string to be identical to `House`.  `false` evaluations will be treated as `0` and `true` evaluations will be treated as `1`.  By writing the `$b` data on the left side of the operator, descending sorting is implemented.  The `House` object will be the only object to evaluate as `true`, and because it is the first sorting condition, it will take priority as the first object in the array of objects.

For the other objects that that do not contain `House`, the second sorting condition is evaluated.  By writing `$b`'s `Total` value on the left side and the `$a`'s `Total` values on the right side, descending sorting is again used -- this puts objects with higher totals before objects with lower totals.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/D2uWq))

```
usort(
    $objects,
    fn($a, $b) =>
         [$b->Name === 'House', $b->Total]
         <=>
         [$a->Name === 'House', $a->Total]
);
```

---

For completeness, you can also use `array_multisort()` but it will be less efficient than `usort()` in this case because multiple function calls will be necessary to prepare the sorting columns. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/an3SS))

```
array_multisort(
    array_map(fn($obj) => $obj->Name !== 'House', $objects), // ASC puts falses before trues
    array_column($objects, 'Total'),
    SORT_DESC,
    $objects
);
```